# Querying table twice within single select

Tags: sql, join

I have to create a query which selects data from one table, then uses the data to query another table column twice and return both results in a single data set

I already have the basic query set up which correctly queries the first table and returns data for a single result

```
select a.timestamp, a.order_no, a.item_no, a.status_code, a.qty, b.text 
from ordhist a, 
order_text b 
where a.order_no = 1 and a.status_code = 120 and b.text_nr = 707 and a.order_no = b.text_order_no and a.item_no = b.text_item_no;
```

So my issue is that every entry has two text numbers that I need to check for (707 and 708). An example result should be

18/10/19, 1, 1, 120, 1, 708 text, 707 text

18/19/19, 1, 2, 120, 5, 708 text, 707 text

I know I can't just change the b.text_nr check for both 707 and 708 because this wouldn't combine the results into the single line but rather return results for both 707 and 708 entries

Any ideas?

EDIT:

So I've done some work and managed to get it to work in a test system. However have hit an issue now in that the test system is using Oracle 10... and the production system (at another site) is using Oracle 8. I'm not sure the best way to transpose this now

```
select timestamp, o.order_no, o.item_no, o.status_code, o.qty, a.pt_text, b.pt_text
from ordhist o
INNER JOIN AUF_POS_TEXTE a on (o.order_no = a.pt_order_no and a.pt_text_nr = 708 and a.pt_order_pos = 0)
INNER JOIN AUF_POS_TEXTE b on (o.order_no = b.pt_order_no and b.pt_text_nr = 707 and o.item_no = b.pt_order_pos)
where o.order_no = 701067652 and o.status_code = 120;
```

Comment: This is not clear. "check for", "combine" & "return results for both" don't mean anything in particular. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation.

Comment: This was answered 2 days ago. Did the answer help? "get it to work"--get what to work? And what is your one clear specific question? If you have a new question, post a new question, don't edit your post if it invalidates any reasonable answers to your first question; click on edit & click on roll back on the version to restore this post to. Otherwise--Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of right now. Also you are still unclear, you still don't say what you want, and you still haven't given the rest of a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting the question as your wanting rows from `ordhist` where the corresponding `order_text` has at least one row with 707 and one with 708.

```
select oh.timestamp, oh.order_no, oh.item_no, oh.status_code, oh.qty 
from ordhist oh
     order_text ot
     on oh.order_no = ot.text_order_no and
        oh.item_no = ot.text_item_no
where oh.order_no = 1 and oh.status_code = 120 and
      ot.text_nr in (707, 708)
group by oh.timestamp, oh.order_no, oh.item_no, oh.status_code, oh.qty
having count(distinct ot.text_nr) = 2;
```